# can i pass the xml object with return type of object in web services

Tags: java, xml, web-services

I am new in Web Service Development. I have one concept. please let give me answer.  Any one Java web services,  xml object is set as parameter and with their return type. example

```
public object find(Object object){
    ...........
    return object;
}
```

please any one give me how to do this Concept? advanced Thanks...

Comment: Yes we could achieve it with pojo mapping

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use jaxb marshelling and pass the xml element as object

```
      public String asString(
                    JAXBContext pContext, 
                    Object pObject)
                        throws 
                            JAXBException {

java.io.StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

Marshaller marshaller = pContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
marshaller.marshal(pObject, sw);

return sw.toString();
 }
```